# How to add product image and description in product structured data (Schema.org) in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, schema, structured-data

I am using this to add a custom field to each product's schema

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', function( $markup, $product ) {
    if( is_product() ) {
        $markup['brand'] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'brand', TRUE);
    }
```

I also need to add the product's image url and description to the schema, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you already looked here? https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-structured-data.html#source-view.328

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano yes, and I was also under the impression that Woocommerce already adds image and description in the structured data, but when you test a product url in Google's Rich Snippets Test Tool, you will be getting errors/warnings about missing image and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`woocommerce_structured_data_product`** hook already runs on the product page so you don't need the `is_product()` check.

As reported in the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-structured-data.html#source-view.328), it is executed inside the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook.

You can override structured data like this:

```
// overwrites structured data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product',  'set_structured_data', 99, 2 );
function set_structured_data( $markup, $product ) {    
    $markup['brand'] = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'brand', true );
    $markup['image'] = wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id() );
    $markup['description'] = wp_strip_all_tags( $product->get_short_description() ? $product->get_short_description() : $product->get_description() );
    return $markup;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

On the product page, find the `<script type="application/ld+json">` element, it should look something like this:

[image]

Then check if the `brand`, `image` and `description` fields are valued.

You can find a full list of fields to add to **product structured data** here:

- [Product - Schema.org Type](https://schema.org/Product)

**If you want to check the validity of the structured data** *you can enter the entire script* in the **Code** section of the [Rich Results Test - Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) page *(instead of the product page url)*.

Some useful links:

- [Structured data for products](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Structured-data-for-products)
- [Rich Results Tools and Reports](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/9350399?hl=en&ref_topic=9456557)

Related answer:

- [WooCommerce: Adding product schema attribute ean/identifier_exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514082/woocommerce-adding-product-schema-attribute-ean-identifier-exists/66516267#66516267)