# Add the ean code (gtin) in the structured data of the product (Schema.org) in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, schema, product

I am using this snippet to display ean value for gtin in Woocommerce's product schema:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'filter_woocommerce_structured_data_product', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_structured_data_product( $markup, $product ) { 
if ( empty( $markup[ 'gtin8' ] ) ) {
    $markup[ 'gtin8' ] = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ean', true );
}

return $markup;
}
```

This works but I need to set "identifier_exists" markup to products that don't have the custom field ean set. How can I modify my snippet to show the ean value in the markup if it exists, and add the identifier_exists attribute = false to products that don't have an ean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'custom_schema', 99, 2 );
function custom_schema( $markup, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'ean' );
    $length = strlen($value);

    if ( ! empty($value) ) {
        $markup['identifier_exists'] = true;
        $markup['gtin'.$length]      = $value;
    } else {
        $markup['identifier_exists'] = false;
    }
    return $markup;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: Your code does exactly the same as the code above. Unfortunately Google still gives errors and does not accept the "identifier_exists" in Merchant Center.

Answer (score -1):

The `gtin` field **must be set based on its length**.
[Here](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6386198?hl=en) you will find the complete documentation with all available fields.

> The `gtin` must be of type text *(not numeric)*.

Finally, the `gtin` field is optional. **If your product does not have the EAN code** *(or any other identifier)* **you can simply not set the `gtin`**.

Even if you set the `identifier_exists` field to **no** or **false** you will still see the *"No global identifier provided (e.g., gtin, mpn, isbn) (optional)"* warning. You can just ignore it. In fact, it is not reported in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6386198?hl=en).

You can do some tests here: https://search.google.com/test/rich-results

```
// set the gtin in the structured data of the product
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'custom_schema', 99, 2 );
function custom_schema( $markup, $product ) {
    // get the product identifier
    $ean = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ean', true );
    // set gtin based on length
    switch ( strlen($ean) ) {
        case 8:
            $markup['gtin8'] = (string)$ean;
            break;
        case 12:
            $markup['gtin12'] = (string)$ean;
            break;
        case 13:
            $markup['gtin13'] = (string)$ean;
            break;
        case 14:
            $markup['gtin14'] = (string)$ean;
            break;
        default:
            $markup['identifier_exists'] = 'no';
            break;
    }
    return $markup;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Related answer:

- [Adding product image and description to Woocommerce schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66397008/adding-product-image-and-description-to-woocommerce-schema)

Comment: I only have 8-digit EANS, would I still need the other? Also, while the code works, Google still shows errors that no gtin, ean or mpn is set even if identifier_exists is defined as no...

Comment: Sorry, I want to remove my second comment.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The **gtin** is an optional field.

Comment: But what about this https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324478?hl=en

Comment: This refers to products imported to Google Merchant Center (Google Shopping). We're talking about structured product data here (for Google search results). For the Merchant Center, as reported in the link in your comment, you must set the `identifier_exists` field to `no` and the `gtin` field empty. What is authentic in structured data is [schema.org](https://schema.org/Product).

Comment: I need the structured data for Merchant Center though.That's why I was asking my question. Sorry if I forgot to add that...

Comment: I understand. However my answer is always valid. Google Merchant Center uses structured product data only to update price and stock status. If a product's gtin is not set in structured data (and not even in Google Merchant Center) the **sku** field of the structured data will be used as an identifier (make sure its value is identical to the Google Merchant Center **id** field). [Here](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/3246284?hl=en) you will find more information.